# Clues on theorem proving tools?

Tags: logic, theorem-proving

I'm trying to prove $[a \cup (b \cap c ) = (a\cup b)\cap (a\cup c)]$ with *Mathematica*. But I don't know what function I should use. I've rewritten the sentence in the following way:

```
(a) ∨ (b ∧ c) == (a ∨ b) ∧ (a ∨ c)
```

With $a$ being a symbol for $x\in a$ and the same for the other letters. I've just tried to evaluate:

```
(a) ∨ (b ∧ c) == (a ∨ b) ∧ (a ∨ c)
```

but nothing happened. I've also tried to use:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[(a) ∨ (b ∧ c) == (a ∨ 
  b) ∧ (a ∨ c), {a, b, c}]
```

but I'm not sure I understand the output. I am aware of the `BooleanTable`, but I'd like to use some more advanced theorem proving tools in *Mathematica*. Could you give me a hint of where to go?

Comment: Try `Resolve` and `SameQ`.

Comment: `BooleanTable[{a, b, c} -> 
   Equal @@ {(a) \[Or] (b \[And] c), (a \[Or] b) \[And] (a \[Or] 
        c)}, {a, b, c}] // Column`

Answer (score 6):

You can compose [`TautologyQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TautologyQ.html) and [`Equivalent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html)

```
ClearAll[bEq]
bEq = TautologyQ @* Equivalent;
```

***Examples:***

```
bEq[a && (b || c), a && b || a && c]
```

> True

```
table = Table[BooleanConvert[BooleanFunction[30, {a, b, c}], form],
  {form, {"DNF", "CNF", "ANF", "NAND", "NOR", "ITE"}}]
```

> {(a && ! b && ! c) || (! a && b) || (! a && 
>       c),
>    (! a || ! b) && (! a || ! c) && (a || b || c),
>    a ⊻ b ⊻ 
>     c ⊻ (b && c),
>   (a ⊼ ! b ⊼ ! c) ⊼ (! a ⊼ 
>       b) ⊼ (! a ⊼ 
>       c),
>   (! a ⊽ ! b) ⊽ (! a ⊽ ! c) ⊽ (a ⊽ 
>       b ⊽ c),
>    If[a, If[b, False, If[c, False, True]], 
>     If[b, True, If[c, True, False]]]}

```
bEq @ table
```

> True

From [`Equivalent >> Properties and Relations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html):

> [`Equivalent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html) is effectively [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) for Boolean expressions.

Answer (score 4):

[FindEquationalProof](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEquationalProof.html) is available as an option:

```
booleanAxioms = 
 {ForAll[{a, b}, and[a, b] == and[b, a]],
  ForAll[{a, b}, or[a, b] == or[b, a]],
  ForAll[{a, b}, and[a, or[b, not[b]]] == a],
  ForAll[{a, b}, or[a, and[b, not[b]]] == a],
  ForAll[{a, b, c}, and[a, or[b, c]] == or[and[a, b], and[a, c]]],
  ForAll[{a, b, c}, or[a, and[b, c]] == and[or[a, b], or[a, c]]]}
setOperationAxioms = 
 {ForAll[{a, b, x}, 
   and[member[x, a], member[x, b]] == member[x, intersection[a, b]]],
  ForAll[{a, b, x}, 
   or[member[x, a], member[x, b]] == member[x, union[a, b]]]}
FindEquationalProof[
 ForAll[{x, a, b, c},
  member[x, union[a, intersection[b, c]]] ==
   member[x, intersection[union[a, b], union[a, c]]]] , 
 Union[booleanAxioms, setOperationAxioms]]
```